# Content disposition when downloading from google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, content-disposition

I would like to use a direct link to https://storage.cloud.google.com/mybucket/myfile.pdf?response-content-disposition=attachment;%20filename=myfile.pdf (this is the link that gets created when browsing the GCS in the Cloud Console itself.

The work-around is going to https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/mybucket/o/myfile.pdf?alt=media but that's obviously not a very pretty URL.

Has the API changed any that response-content-disposition is actually something else now?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? Has the response for the first URL changed?